# How to update data by push array with condition mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im using mongoose and I just use mongo DB.

Here is my schema

```
date: { type: String },
branchDetailId: { type: String },
times: [
  {
    time: { type: String },
    totalOrderCount: { type: String },
    orderId: [String],
  },
],
```

Here is my data in array times

```
"times": [
{
    "orderId": [
        "5e8178b1b315ee022277e80b",
        "5e8178b1b315ee022277e80b"
    ],
    "_id": ObjectID("5e82ed1c4e553a0874cdad94"),
    "deleted": false,
    "time": "11.00",
    "totalOrderCount": "2",
    "deletedAt": null
},
{
    "orderId": [
        "5e8178b1b315ee022277e803b",
        "5e8178b1b315ee0222773e80b"
    ],
    "_id": ObjectID("5e82ed1c4e553a0874cdad95"),
    "deleted": false,
    "time": "12.00",
    "totalOrderCount": "2",
    "deletedAt": null
}
],
```

I and I've my orderId

`"ertertretretet"` //here is example order Id

I want to pust my orderId into time.times : 11:00

something like this

```
if(times.times == "11.00"){
 push orderId into DB in object time == 11.00 filed
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) (or [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) if you want to avoid duplicate) with positional [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator to solve your problem. Something like this:

```
db.your_collection.update({"times.time": "11.00"}, {$push: {"times.$.orderId": "your_orderId"}})
```

Comment: Can I check in here  only not duplicate orderId can push

Comment: If so you can use $addToSet instead of $push: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/